# Angular: I have to get dispatch value from store, but unable to get

Tags: javascript, angular

**Angular: I have to get dispatch value from store, but unable to get:-**

My Code Snippet:

```
....
....
this.backEnd.getAllStudents().subscribe( students => this.store.dispatch({ type: SET_STUDENTS, payload: students }));
....
....
```

I have to fetch dispatched list of students from angular store..

I tried with:

```
this.store.select('students');
```

But **its showing whole angular object.. please suggest me changes or ideas to get student list from store.**

Comment: have you created reducer for Student and passed reducer in `StoreModule.forRoot({ students: studentsReducer })` in imports array of `app.module.ts`?

Comment: please give me any example

Comment: Hope this example helps https://fireship.io/lessons/angular-ngrx-redux-starter-guide/